# Android immersive fullscreen mode on a single fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to apply immersive full screen on one of my 3 fragments,  just like given in the tutorial as:

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    View decorView = getActivity(). getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

And called the method from the fragments's  `onCreateView` method.

I expected this to effect the fragment only, but instead, its effecting all fragments.

How can I force the immersive screen to effect a screen single fragment only?

Answer (score 1):

You apply immersive mode to activity's decor view and as I understand you have a single activity application, so it applies to your "root" activity. 
Try to exit immerse mode on destroying of fragment. For example:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//...
    Handler().post {
        activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
        }
//...
}

//...

override fun onDestroyView() {
//...
    Handler().post {
        activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
    }
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete full view for single fragment for all android version. showSystemUI function call in onViewCreate() or onResume() while hideSystemUI function call on destory() of the fragment.

```
fun Activity.hideSystemUI() {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        val windowInsetsController =
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
        // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    } else {
        val decorView: View = window.decorView
        val uiOptions = decorView.systemUiVisibility
        var newUiOptions = uiOptions
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = newUiOptions
    }

}

fun Activity.showSystemUI() {
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
        val windowInsetsController =
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
        // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
        windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    } else {
        val decorView: View = window.decorView
        val uiOptions = decorView.systemUiVisibility
        var newUiOptions = uiOptions
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE.inv()
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN.inv()
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION.inv()
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.inv()
        newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY.inv()
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = newUiOptions
    }

}
```

Note: Add this tag in activity theme.

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="P">shortEdges</item>
```

But if you want to handle programmatically go for this.
Add this in showSystemUI.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window?.attributes?.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_DEFAULT
    }
```

Add this in hideSystemUI.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window?.attributes?.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
    }
```